# How to fire once each time on changing directory content with fs.watch?

Tags: node.js, watch

Is there a way to fire ***only once*** on changing directory content with Node.js `fs.watch`? By changing directory content I mean **adding/deleting** bunch of files from it ?

In other words I expect `fs.watch` to fire on the **first event** of the **first file** and ignore any other events for particular changing dir content cycle.

I was able to do this only with `fs.watchFile` But node guys recommend to use `fs.watch` if possible.

> Note: fs.watch() is more efficient than fs.watchFile and fs.unwatchFile. fs.watch should be used instead of fs.watchFile and fs.unwatchFile when possible.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

Comment: You mean it should fire on the first event it receives and ignore any others?

Comment: I would rather say it should fire on the _first event_ of the _first file_ and ignore any other events

Comment: Oh the question is not clear. You wrote you want it to run once. You need to throttle or debounce your listener for some period of time this case.

Comment: I mean run once for particular changing dir cycle. Added notice anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

[Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) patricianly answered this question earlier, but shortly after
deleted his answer:

> You simply stop watching on the first call
>
> ```
> const watcher = fs.watch(somePath, (ev, file) => {
>   watcher.close()
>
>   // logic goes here
>   console.log(`${ev} ${file}`)
> })
> ```

With resurrecting watcher after closing it, we will have 1 shot recurrent behavior as asked in the question:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let dir = './watch1'

function watchOnce()
{
  const watcher = fs.watch(dir, (evt, file) => {
    watcher.close()

    // logic goes here
    console.log(Date(), evt, file)

   // resurrecting watcher after 1 sec
    setTimeout(watchOnce, 1000)
  })
}

watchOnce()
```

> Testing

Creating and deleting 10,000 files 5 times in a raw with 1 seconds delay in between:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do touch {1..10000}; sleep 1; rm {1..10000}; sleep 1; done
```

Verifying that watcher fired exactly 10 times (5 for creating 10,000 files and 5 for deleting 10,000 files):

```
$ node watchers.js
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:44 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:46 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:47 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:49 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:50 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:52 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:53 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:55 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:56 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
Wed Jun 07 2017 12:01:58 GMT+0300 (EEST) rename 1
```

I will not marking my answer as accepted, since credits mostly goes to [Yury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) for his `watcher.close()` idea. And maybe someone else will write more neat solution, since I am not big fun using delay in the function.